# What does "highest number" mean in Draft lottery context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "highest number" mean in Draft lottery context?

Context belongs to 1960s timeline.

Answer (score 1):

During the Vietnam war, American men who were of age for military service were assigned a **draft number** based on their day of birth.  The numbers were assigned randomly to each of the 366 days of the year (the exact process is described in [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_lottery_(1969))).  Those numbers started at 1 (which happened to be assigned to a birth date of July 9th), and the men with a draft number of 1 were drafted first, followed by those who were numbered 2, and so on.  So a **higher draft number** meant that you were less likely to be drafted before the end of the war.

The exact meaning of **highest draft number** would depend on context.  If you just said of a person, "he has the **highest draft number**," without any other context, then that means that his birthdate draft number is 366.  This man would not be drafted until all eligible men born on all 365 other days of the year had already been drafted.  I could even imagine this being used metaphorically to mean "very lucky."

You could also refer to "the **highest draft number called** so far," which would refer to the most recent (thus, the highest) number assigned to men being drafted.  By the end of the war, the **highest draft number called** was 95.

Comment: You would know by your number when to book your travel to Canada.